# How to animate a background image from left to right and from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wish to achieve the following animation using jquery/javascript. I have an image with width 2000px and height 200px. I would like to animate the image from left to right, till it reaches one end and then from right to left. This should continue to give a panoramic view.

I tried the [following script][1] on the internet, but it goes only oneside. I want something like a Panning effect. 
Kindly advice. Thank you

Direct link to code: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Auto-Scrolling-Background-AutoBackgroundScroll-js/js/autoBackgroundScroll.js

```
;(function(){
$.fn.autoBackgroundScroll = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.autoBackgroundScroll.defaults, options);
    var $backslider = $(this);


    var duration = opts.duration;
    var speed = opts.speed;
    var imageWidth = opts.imageWidth;
    var imageHeight = opts.imageHeight;
    var direction1 = opts.direction1;
    var direction2 = opts.direction2;


    var posX = 0;
    var posY = 0;


    scroll(duration, speed, direction1, direction2);


    function scroll(duration, speed, direction1, direction2){
        setInterval(function(){
            if(direction1 == 'right'){
                moveRight();

                if(direction2 == 'top'){
                    moveTop();
                }

                if(direction2 == 'bottom'){
                    moveBottom();
                }

            } else if(direction1 == 'left'){
                moveLeft();

                if(direction2 == 'top'){
                    moveTop();
                }

                if(direction2 == 'bottom'){
                    moveBottom();
                }

            } else if(direction1 == 'bottom'){
                moveBottom();

                if(direction2 == 'right'){
                    moveRight();
                }

                if(direction2 == 'left'){
                    moveLeft();
                }

            } else if(direction1 == 'top'){
                moveTop();

                if(direction2 == 'right'){
                    moveRight();
                }

                if(direction2 == 'left'){
                    moveLeft();
                }

            }

            $backslider.css('background-position', posX + 'px ' + posY + 'px');


            function moveTop(){
                if(posY <= -imageHeight){
                    posY = 0;
                }
                posY -= speed;
            }


            function moveRight(){
                if(posX >= imageWidth){
                    posX = 0;
                }
                posX += speed;
            }


            function moveBottom(){
                if(posY >= imageHeight){
                    posY = 0;
                }
                posY += speed;
            }


            function moveLeft(){
                if(posX <= -imageWidth){
                    posX = 0;
                }
                posX -= speed;
            }

        }, duration);
    }

}

$.fn.autoBackgroundScroll.defaults = {
    direction1: 'right',
    direction2: '',
    duration: 1,
    speed: 0.5
};

})(jQuery);
```

Code courtesy: http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Auto-Scrolling-Background-AutoBackgroundScroll-js.html

Comment: Show us what code you have till now

Comment: You can do that with CSS transitions - simply create a transition that changes the background position from 0 to 100%

Comment: @eithed `background-position: 100% 0` will move background out of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple jQuery animate setting proper `background-position` values for x and y (I suggest using CSS transitions for smoother animation):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  slide();

  setInterval(function() {
    slide();
  }, 10000);
});

function slide() {
  $('body').css({
    'background-position': -2000 + $(window).width() + 'px 0'
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css({
      'background-position': '0 0'
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url('http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Auto-Scrolling-Background-AutoBackgroundScroll-js/img/background.jpg') no-repeat left top transparent;
  transition: background-position 5000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for code. It has helped me to achieve, What i was looking for. However after sometime, the animation stops as well the width if the panning gets lesser. I will paste my code here ( I used another image with 3696px width.

Comment: 'code'
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
  slide();

  setInterval(function() {
    slide();
  }, 10000);
});

function slide() {
  $('body').css({
    'background-position': -3696 + $(window).width() + 'px 0'
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').css({
      'background-position': '0 0'
    });
  }, 5000);
};
        </script>
'code'

Comment: The animation width gets reduced after some time. Any workaround for that issue

Comment: @user483903 Try increasing timing in JS

Comment: I tried that, seems the animation (left to right and right to left) is getting shorter as time passes by.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using CSS animation

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/1000x200/333/ccc.png");
  background-position-x: 50%;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: panoramic;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  width: 444px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  will-change: background-position-x;
}

@keyframes panoramic {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-x: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much